# Hide the jquery datatable pagination buttons when there is no data

Tags: jquery, datatable, pagination

How to hide the jquery datatable pagination buttons when there is no data and display the custom message

Comment: have you forgotten to add server side scripting language tag to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Add code to check

```
if(num of records >0)
{
    // show pagination
}
else
{
    // no records message
}
```

Comment: where to check the condition in the jsp? I want to chk in the jsp and if length=0 then display the custom message or else display the datatable. Can you please be specifc

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. This worked for me. Keep this code inside of datatables code.

```
    jQuery('#table_id').DataTable( {
        // Some stuff here
        "fnDrawCallback":function(){
             if(jQuery('table#table_id td').hasClass('dataTables_empty')){
                jQuery('div.dataTables_paginate.paging_full_numbers').hide();
             } else {
                jQuery('div.dataTables_paginate.paging_full_numbers').show();
             }
        }
    });
```